# Login page with php and mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

I'm trying to build a login page based on a mysql database but it doesn't work. With the code below i always get an empty page instead of a redirect. and `echo $result_row['password'];` doesn't return anything.

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      session_start();

      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

      $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
      $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

      $mysqlhost = "localhost"; // MySQL-Host angeben
      $mysqluser = "***"; // MySQL-User angeben
      $mysqlpwd = "***"; // Passwort angeben

      $connection = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd) or die("Verbindungsversuch fehlgeschlagen");

      $mysqldb="db2507004-bank"; // Gewuenschte Datenbank angeben
      mysql_select_db($mysqldb, $connection) or die("Konnte die Datenbank nicht waehlen.");

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konto WHERE 'username' LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1") 
      or die(mysql_error());

      $result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      echo $result_row['password'];

      // Benutzername und Passwort werden überprüft
      if ($passwort == $result_row['password']) {
       $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       $_SESSION['name'] =  $result_row['name'];

       echo '<meta http-equiv="Location" content="http://testserver.info.cm/konto_show.php/">';
       }
      }
?>
```

Comment: use mysqli or pdo  please

Comment: you did not fetch result

Comment: Also please don't store plain text passwords. This is combination with the first commenter is the worst thing you can do to your users.

Comment: you should not be using LIKE for the compare

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections, switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepare statements

Comment: Giant [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/)? Using antiquated `mysql_query`? Plain-text passwords? **DO NOT** implement user authentication this way or you will get into serious trouble. Where did you learn to do it this way? The best way to do this is to use a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that has a user authentication module you can use instead of writing your own.

Comment: @AwladLiton how do i use mysqli? ok, i forgot to copy that but at least it was in my original php code. i'm going to change it.

Comment: @PeeHaa it's not the final version it's just for testing and i don't think that security is that important if it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Fred -ii- i'm using LIMIT 1 so it should be only one row and i tried a while loop earlier

Comment: **NO**. Code like this has a way of becoming the final version when you're not looking. Seriously. You are making too many mistakes here and they are not little ones either. Why are you writing your own authentication system when there are literally hundreds of them out there that work properly? Sorry to sound so severe but it's code like this that gets people into serious trouble.

Comment: Please read [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @NathanMaier That's bollocks and you know it. I have seen too much of those temporary permanent solutions in my career for that, sorry.

Comment: if you start writing code and you make a mistake on the second line it doesn't make sense to add 500 more that makes it only more difficult to find the mistake. first you have to get it working and then you can think about what has to be improved.

Comment: @NathanMaier I'm all for getting it working and then refactoring it repeatedly until it's better, but this is just **wrong**. While on a technical level it "works", it's an implementation so recklessly bad it could destroy someone's business or career. Please, do not write your own user authentication code, instead use a framework that does it correctly or at the very least use an example that implements [best practices](http://phptherightway.com/). There's a kid who might be [going to jail](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2014/01/teen-reported-security-hole/) because of code like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not fetch result. Try like this:

```
<?php
         if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
          session_start();

          $username = $_POST['username'];
          $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

          $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
          $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

          $mysqlhost = "localhost"; // MySQL-Host angeben
          $mysqluser = "***"; // MySQL-User angeben
          $mysqlpwd = "***"; // Passwort angeben

          $connection = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd) or die("Verbindungsversuch fehlgeschlagen");

          $mysqldb="db2507004-bank"; // Gewuenschte Datenbank angeben
          mysql_select_db($mysqldb, $connection) or die("Konnte die Datenbank nicht waehlen.");

          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konto WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1") 
          or die(mysql_error());
          $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
          echo $row->password;

          // Benutzername und Passwort werden überprüft
          if ($passwort == $row->password) {
           $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           $_SESSION['name'] =  $row->name;

          header("Location http://testserver.info.cm/konto_show.php");
           }
          }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Nathan Maier: did you try this?

Comment: as i already said i fetched it with $result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      echo $result_row['password'];

Comment: and i tried $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
          echo $row->password; too but no difference

Comment: @Nathan Maier:  did you try code? what output or error did you get?

Comment: did you run this query in your sql server with given username? SELECT * FROM konto WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44911/discussion-between-awlad-liton-and-nathan-maier)

Answer (score 2):

The result of `mysql_query()` function should be fetched for using in php.you cannot use it like that .
you can use :

[mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

[mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

[mysql_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

by example, you can use it like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM konto WHERE 'username' LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo $row[1];
}
```

AND, by the way, **The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead**

Comment: The best answer is to start over with PDO.

Comment: @tadman This, however, does not address the problem at hand. PDO is a good tool, but it's not the only one. Without any sort of reference, getting started guide, or advice, your comment adds nothing.

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers there's you resource not prevent crap from spreading

Comment: PDO is the *minimum* when developing new code like this. It's much better to use a proper [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) where this would already be implemented. [This PHP guide](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps avoid pitfalls like this.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing your redirect using a `meta` tag, but if this is the entirety of your script, it's not part of a well-formed HTML document (the only other output is from `echo $result_row['password'];`), and so I expect that's the reason it's not working.

Try using a 301 HTTP header, maybe something like this:

```
header('Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/konto_show.php');
```

(Also, be careful of SQL injection vulnerabilities in your SQL statements. Always run user input through the relevant MySQL escape function.)

Comment: you should full the full URI for the location

Comment: True, although what the spec says is likely to change in the future, but I'll adjust the answer as we're all forced to live in the present... :'(

Answer (score 1):

In the doc, it is writing that mysql_query return a resource.
you must use a fetch function to obtain a result.

In your case you want to verify if the "int" the function is return is 0 or more.
Then use mysql_fetch_row 
Doc :  php.net/mysql_fetch_row

it will put the result in an array.

```
result_row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

then compare your value :

```
if (result_row[0])
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You my go with this way:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konto WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1") ;
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row==1 &&  $passwort == $result_row['password']){
   $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['name'] =  $result_row['name'];

   echo '<meta http-equiv="Location" content="http://testserver.info.cm/konto_show.php/">';
   }
}
```